# SQL Server - logical question - Get rank from IDs

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to write a query to solve a logical problem using Redshift POSTGRES 8.

Input column is a bunch of IDs and Order IDs and desired output is basically a rank of the ID as you can see in the screenshot.
(I'm sorry I'm not allowed to embed images into my StackOverflow posts yet)

If you could help me answer this question using SQL, that would be great! Thanks

[image: "Input and Output columns"]

Data

| order id | id | size | desired output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | abcd | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | efgh | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | efgh | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | efgh | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | efgh | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | aa | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | aa | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | bb | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | bb | 2 | 2 |

Comment: Please don't include links to images of data.  Use the editor's markdown language to include the data as formatted text.

Comment: sql server or mysql?

Comment: MySQL8+ has functionality not present in MySQL 5.x, and neither of them are the same thing as SQL Server (a product from Microsoft) - Please could you specify which DBMS you're using, and specify which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY order_item_id ORDER BY id)   AS desired_result
FROM
  your_table
```

`DENSE_RANK()` creates sequences starting from `1` according to the `ORDER BY`.

Any rows with the same `ID` will get the same value, and where `RANK()` would skip values in the event of ties `DENSE_RANK()` does not.

The `PARTITION BY` allows new sequences to be created for each different `order_item_id`.