# Redshift Postgres 8

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to write a query to solve a logical problem using Redshift Postgres 8.

Input column is a bunch of Order IDs and Step Group IDs and desired output is basically a sequence of the IDs as you can see in the screenshot.

If you could help me answer this question, that would be great, thanks!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU3j7.png]

This is a follow up question from
[SQL Server - logical question - Get rank from IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67106189/sql-server-logical-question-get-rank-from-ids)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. How is the output supposed to be calculated? What have you already tried? Where are you struggling? This is not an excel to SQL converter website :-)

Comment: I essentially have a table with the first four columns (achieved through a bunch of joins), and now I'm looking to add a column (the output here) which gives me the running frequency within each ID instead of the running sequence within each order item id.

Comment: Sorry, I only see a bunch of numbers without context - please edit your question to include that information and walk us through an example of how the values are calculated. It may seem obvious to you, it isn't to people looking at this for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to partition the table by the first two columns and then to number the rows in each partition, you can use this query:

```sql
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_item_id, id ORDER BY order_item_id, id) FROM table;
```